# user picture changes after saving profile

Tags: users, media

to solve a problem related to the expiration date of some users on my website I made a module that updates just the "expiration" field when a user successfully place an order.
The structure of the module is very simple and is as follows:

```
<?php

/*
 * Implementation of hook_order()
 */
function update_exp_date_uc_order($op, &$arg1, $arg2)
{
  if ($op == 'update' &&
      $arg1->order_status == 'payment_received' &&
      $arg2 == 'completed')
  {
    // parameters
    $exp_date_field_name = 'field_participant_expiration';
    $exp_date_field_name_aut = 'field_participant_expiration_aut'; 

    // get order user ID
    $order_user_id = $arg1->uid;
    // load the user
    $user_fields = user_load($order_user_id);
    // get the current expiration date of the user
    $current_exp_date = field_get_items('user', $user_fields, $exp_date_field_name);
    $current_exp_date_aut = field_get_items('user', $user_fields, $exp_date_field_name_aut);
    $current_exp_date = $current_exp_date[0]['value'];

    if ( isset($current_exp_date_aut) && !empty($current_exp_date_aut) ) {

        if ( strtotime($current_exp_date_aut) > strtotime('now') ) {

            $edit_exp_date = array($exp_date_field_name => array(
                'und' => array(
                            0 => array(
                                'value' => gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($current_exp_date_aut)+(365*24*60*60))
                                ),
                            ),
                ),
            );
        }
        else {
            $edit_exp_date = array($exp_date_field_name => array(
            'und' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'value' => gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 year'))
                            ),
                        ),
            ),
        );

        }
    }
    else {
        $edit_exp_date = array($exp_date_field_name => array(
            'und' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'value' => gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 year'))
                            ),
                        ),
            ),
        );

    }
    user_save($user_fields, $edit_exp_date);




  }
}
```

It works as expected but I just realized that it deletes the user profile picture.
Do you guys have any idea why?

To quickly solve this issue I was thinking of doing something like:

```
$temp_picture = $user_fields = user_load($order_user_id);
$temp_picture = $user_fields->picture;

user_save($user_fields, $edit_exp_date);
user_save($user_fields, $temp_picture);
```

I am sure there is a more compact way to code it and suggestions are more than welcome.

My real questions are:

- why are the pictures deleted after saving the user? (I set an automatic profile picture, which doesn't work, but it could be related...)
- is the quick fix I posted above gonna work?

Thank you in advance.
Guido

Comment: To get the user ID I use: `$order_user_id = $arg1->uid;` What do you mean with "only partial user load"?

Comment: ok, thanks for the hint. Due to my relatively limited knowledge of drupal I am not fully sure if THIS is causing the problem, but the picture deletion happens only after a user renew the subscription and therefore triggers the module to update the expiration.
I am not familiar with the `dpm` command. What should I expect to see? thanks

Comment: I tried what you suggested. First off, thanks for letting me know, it is an amazing dev tool that I will be using a lot. 
Using it I did verify that the module in question is actually making the change but the tries I made were using my administrator profile and the picture stayed there. Do you think it might be a permission problem?

Comment: I have no idea mate, it's going to need a bit more digging on your part.  I'm deleting my comments above as they no longer add anything to the question, and will do the same with this one later.

Comment: Alright. thank you for the help. it helped troubleshoot anyways. I will post when and if I will find the reason of this odd behavior.